# form input does not get saved in JavaScript function. Why?

Tags: javascript, user-input

I can not find why this does not work. "document.getElementById("number").value" won't "return" in function..
My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Currency_Converter.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/> 
 </head> 
 <body>

 <div class="container">
 <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
 <form id="amount">Dollar amount &ensp;$<input id="number" type="number" name="number" onkeyup="getDollarAmount();" onchange="getDollarAmount();" placeholder="type dollar amount here" ></form>      
</div>     
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="Currency_Converter.js"></script>
</html>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function getDollarAmount() {
  var dollarAmount = document.getElementById("number").value;
    return (dollarAmount);
} 
console.log(getDollarAmount());
```

My "function getDollarAmount()" does not return the number put into the form. When I "console.log (dollarAmount)" I get my input. When I take out the "document.getElementById("number").value" and replace it with a number, (ex.: 5) the "getDollarAmount" function returns the number (5).

Obviously, the issue is with "document.getElementById("number").value" since the function works in every other way. What do I need to do to get "document.getElementById("number").value" to be returned to "getDollarAmount()"?

Comment: Did you try to get the element in the JQuery style `$("#number")` and `console.log` that value

Comment: If you enter a number into the field then run `console.log(getDollarAmount());` in the console, what does it print?

Comment: Did you checked if JS is executing the function?

Comment: Yes. If I change "return" to "console.log(dollarAmount)" the console shows numbers typed.

Comment: JS is executing the function. console.log(getDollarAmount()) is empty, but executed

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var dollarAmount = $("#number").val();
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate he imported jquery in html

Comment: Thank you, but the jQuery performs exactly like the JS.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake here is that you are returning the value instead of assigning the dollarAmount variable to the input value attribute.

Apart from that the idea to return the converted currency value in the same place you type the amount you want to convert to is not a good practice and will be confusing.

You should have a place to input and a place to show the converted value. It's a better user experience and better for you.

You don't need jQuery. Here's an example:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("number");

el.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    //You need to assign the value to a variable
   var dollarAmount = getDollarAmount();
});

function getDollarAmount() {
  return el.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="number" type="number" name="number" placeholder="type dollar amount here" value="0" >
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am only trying to capture input in this function. The JS  not included, brings in API currency data. I need to capture the dollarAmount input so I can multiply it by my API data. With getDollarAmount I just need to capture dollarAmount input.

Comment: You are welcome. 

You can use my example to create an eventListener for "change" event and call your getDollarAmount() function from there.

in you getDollarAmount() function you can simply return el.value. This way getDollarAmount will return the value of the input.

Comment: Can you show me how to have getDollarAmount to return dollarAmount input? With the function provided, how do I change it to show user input? I will multiply by currency data later. "function getDollarAmount() {
  var dollarAmount = document.getElementById("number").value;
    return (dollarAmount);
} 
console.log(getDollarAmount());"

Comment: I simplified the HTML for you. Thanks

Comment: I altered the code for you.
The function returns the value of the input but you need to assign it to a variable if you want to do something with it.

Comment: Mario, you have helped me with the eventListener, BUT I do not understand where to put the variable assignment so that I can use the output. I apologize for being such a noobie. Are you able to give an example?

Comment: I keep getting the same advice - "Build something, that is how you will learn." I saw this Currency Converter and wondered how it worked, then began trying to reconstruct it. This has been fun AND frustrating. I find myself dreaming about my code, but I know so little code. Mario helped me with an eventListener, and now I can console.log the function, where before I could only console.log a local variable. If I can get to a point where I can take my output and multiply it by another output my life will have become much better :-)

Comment: That is a completely new topic. Using my example, if you declare var dollarAmount = 0; under the  var el = document.getElementById("number"); than inside the eventListener you can simple assign the value to dollarAmount such as dollarAmount = getDollarAmount(); without the "var" word behind it.

This way you can use the dollarAmount anywhere on your application and multiply it by anything you want.

You read more about functions, events and scope in javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `console.log()` is not getting called recursively while the value being returned by the `onkeyup` keeps changing.

```
  function getDollarAmount() {
    var dollarAmount = document.getElementById("number").value;
    return (dollarAmount);
  } 
  document.getElementById("number").onkeyup= () =>  {console.log(getDollarAmount())};
```